# set text to SubElement which has more than one text field in XML using ElementTree Python specifically using xpath query if possible

Tags: python, xml, xpath

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
  <doc1>
    <branch name="testing" hash="1cdf045c">
        text,source
    </branch>
    <some name="release01" hash:hashing="f200013e">
        <sub-branch name="subrelease01">
            xml,sgml
        </sub-branch>
    </branch>
    <bsome name="invalid">
    </branch>
   </doc1>
</doc>
```

I wrote something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree

filename='/testxml'

tree = etree.parse(filename)

root = tree.getroot()

print root

primary = etree.Element("{http://schemas.dmtf.org/xxx/doc/1}doc")

secondary = etree.SubElement(primary, "{http://schemas.dmtf.org/xxx/doc/1}some name")

secondary.text = ????

print(etree.tostring(primary, pretty_print=True))
```

I would want to change the value for `hash:hashing`...
If possible I want use xpath query for example `/doc/doc1/some name/@hash:hashing`
to do this task...
Please help....Thank you!

Comment: `Xpath` cannot be used to modify `xml` source

Comment: I understand that. Could you please me solve the above script